# Simple Angular JS expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to do some very simple angularJS expressions. I would like to add the number for total liabilities to the number for preferred stock in the plunker linked below. I was able to use a filter to multiple the inventory by 50% and the accounts receivable by 75%. However, I think these can just be done as expressions as well. It seems also that the application is considering the liabilities and preferred stock inputs as strings. Thanks for your help!

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="namesList">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AngularJS Venn Diagram</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
   Cash 
  <input name="A" cols="100" rows="20" ng-model="title" placeholder="Enter    words for Box A"></input>
  <br>
  Net Receivables
  <input name="B" cols="100" rows="20" ng-model="title2" placeholder="Enter words for Box B"></input>
  <br>
  Inventory
  <input name="C" cols="100" rows="20" ng-model="title3" placeholder="Enter words for Box B"></input>
   <br>
   Total Liabilities
    <input name="D" cols="100" rows="20" ng-model="title4" placeholder="Enter words for Box B"></input>
   <br>
   Preferred Stock
    <input name="E" cols="100" rows="20" ng-model="title5" placeholder="Enter words for Box B"></input>
    <br>
    Stock Outstanding
    <input name="F" cols="100" rows="20" ng-model="title6" placeholder="Enter words for Box B"></input>


<br>    
Cash total: {{title}}
<br>    
Receivables total: {{title2|receivables}}
<br>    
Inventory total: {{title3|inventory}}
<br>    
Liabilities + Preferred Stock: {{int(title4*1 + title5*1)}}
<br>    
Shares Outstanding: {{title6}}
<br>    

</div>

<!-- Vendor libraries -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>


<script>
'use strict';
angular.module('namesList', [])
  .filter('receivables', function() {     
        return function(input) {

        return input*.75;
    };
  })

    .filter('inventory', function() {     
        return function(input2) {

        return input2 * .5;
    };
  })


        .filter('test', function() {      
        return function(input2) {

        return "test";
    };
  })


        .filter('test', function() {      
        return function(input2) {

        return "test";
    };
  })




</script>

<script>
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.factory('serviceId', function() {
 return function(input1, input2) {
 return input1 +input2;
 });

</script>

<script>
'use strict';
(function(){
  function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.title = 0;
    $scope.title2 = 0;
    $scope.title3 = 0;
    $scope.title4 = 0;
    $scope.title5 = 0;
    $scope.title6 = 0;
    $scope.LiaPref = 0;
    $scope.both = 0;
    $scope.addData = function () {

  };
  }
  angular.module('namesList')
    .controller('TestCtrl', TestCtrl);

})()
</script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/o5nWP3zoF7fszleloFek?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is why Liabilities and Preferred Stock are being concatenated as strings then it's because you are missing the `type` attributes on your `<input />` tags.

If those values are supposed to be numbers then use `type="number"` like in the first example [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D).